# How to run docker image prepared locally in Sagemaker?

Tags: docker, amazon-sagemaker

I have a train.py and using a docker pushed an image from local to AWS ECR.
But i am getting this error

```
       The primary container for production variant variant-1 did not pass the ping 
       health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint.
```

Here is the complete **Docker file.** What am I missing.

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN python -m pip install sagemaker-training snowflake-connector-python[pandas] \
pandas scikit-learn boto3 numpy joblib sagemaker flask gevent gunicorn

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/ml:${PATH}"


# Set up the program in the image
COPY pred_demo_sm/train.py /opt/ml/code/train.py
COPY pred_demo_sm/serve /opt/ml/code/serve
COPY pred_demo_sm/output /opt/ml/output
COPY pred_demo_sm/model /opt/ml/model

WORKDIR /opt/ml

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3.7", "/opt/ml/code/train.py"]
```

Here is the complete **.sh file** which builds and pushes the image to AWS ECR

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script shows how to build the Docker image and push it to ECR to be ready for use
# by SageMaker.

# The argument to this script is the image name. This will be used as the image on the local
# machine and combined with the account and region to form the repository name for ECR.
image=$1

if [ "$image" == "" ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <image-name>"
    exit 1
fi

chmod +x pred_demo_sm/train.py
chmod +x pred_demo_sm/serve
chmod +x pred_demo_sm/model/*

# Get the account number associated with the current IAM credentials
account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    exit 255
fi


# Get the region defined in the current configuration (default to us-west-2 if none defined)
region=$(aws configure get region)
region=${region:-us-west-2}


fullname="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${image}:latest"

# If the repository doesn't exist in ECR, create it.

aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "${image}" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${image}" > /dev/null
fi

# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
aws ecr get-login-password --region "${region}" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "${account}".dkr.ecr."${region}".amazonaws.com

# Build the docker image locally with the image name and then push it to ECR
# with the full name.

docker build  -t ${image}
docker tag ${image} ${fullname}

docker push ${fullname}
```

The training job gets successfully completed in Sagemaker.
But fails while deploying the model in sagemaker.

Comment: Exception during training: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/opt/ml/model/model.joblib'
In cloudwatch

Answer (score 0):

Within your Dockerfile, could you try replacing the COPY, WORKDIR, and ENTRYPOINT commands with the following.

```
COPY  pred_demo_sm/opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program
```

Make sure that your serve file is executable as well.